# Show that M is closed convex and find the minimum norm

Tags: functional-analysis

Let M={$y=(y_1,...,y_n) \subset C^n: y_1+...+y_n=1$}. Show that M is closed, convex, and find the element of minimum norm in M.

**Prove M is convex**

Proof: A set $ M \subset C^n$ is convex if for every $x,y \epsilon M$ and every $0 \leq t \leq 1$, we have $tx+(1-t)y \epsilon M$.

Let $x,y \epsilon M$ such that $x_1+...+x_n=1$ and $y_1+...+y_n=1$

$\rightarrow t(x_1+...+x_n)=t$ and $(1-t)(y_1+...+y_n)=1-t$

$\rightarrow t(x_1+...+x_n)+(1-t)(y_1+...+y_n)=t+1-t=1$

$\rightarrow tx+(1-t)y=1$

$\rightarrow tx+(1-t)y \epsilon M$. Hence M is convex.

**Find the element of minimum norm in M**

We know that $C^n$ is a Hilbert space. By a theorem, 
"If $C^n$ is a Hilbert space and M is convex and closed set, then for every $p \epsilon C^n$ the function $d:M \rightarrow$ **R** where $d(x)=||x-p||$ has a minimum for $\bar{x} \epsilon M$.

i.e. $dist(P,M)=inf_{x \epsilon M}||x-p||=||\bar{x}-p||$

**Prove that M is closed**

Can anyone assist me in this part? Also if you can check the parts above I will appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof of convexity is fine.

One way to prove that $M$ is closed is consider the function $f(y) = y_1+\dots+y_n$. Since it is continuous, the set $f^{-1}(\{1\})$ is closed. This set is exactly $M$. More generally, for any continuous linear functional $f$ and any scalar $a$ the set $f^{-1}(\{a\})$ is closed and convex.

Alternatively, you can show that the complement is open: given $y\notin M$, let $\epsilon = |y_1+\dots+y_n-1|/n$ and show that if $\|z-y\|<\epsilon$ then $z\notin M$.

Concerning the minimum norm: your argument is correct. Although, since this Hilbert space happens to be finite-dimensional, convexity isn't essential: minimum distance to any closed set is attained. More importantly, it seems you are asked to **find** an element of minimal norm, not just to prove its existence.

Suggestion: apply the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to $x\cdot y$ where $x = (1,1,\dots,1)$.

Comment: How can we find the element by applying Cauchy-Schwarz inequality?